# Count (Distinct) with an Over Clause

Tags: count, distinct

I am looking for a way to Count Distinct using a Parition.

Here is what I currently have.

```
Select
     MasterID
     ,TxnCode
     ,TxnDate
     ,PriceDate
     ,Quantity
From
MH
Order By 
TxnCode
```

What I would like to do is Count the Distinct PriceDates for each TxnCode and Return that as a Column called PriceChanges.

I know you can't do a

```
Count(Distinct PriceDate) Over (Partition by TxnCode)
```

But is there a simple way to do this?

Here is an Example of the Overall Data in the Table:

```
ID      TxnCode     PriceDate           PriceCharged
2   1514000 2013-10-01 15:49:00 2.0600
2   1514000 2013-10-01 15:49:00 2.0600
2   1514000 2013-10-01 15:49:00 2.0600
2   1516000 2013-03-13 11:24:00 4.4900
2   1516000 2013-03-13 11:24:00 4.4900
2   1516000 2013-10-01 15:49:00 4.0200
2   1516000 2013-10-01 15:49:00 4.0200
2   22120   2009-05-04 23:27:00 0.1500
2   22120   2009-05-04 23:27:00 0.1500
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with partitions, but if if I follow your question correctly and you want to count the distinct PriceDates you should be able to do this with a group by instead of using distinct

```
Select PriceDate, Count(*) as Count
     MasterID
    ,TxnCode
    ,TxnDate
    ,PriceDate
    ,Quantity
From
MH
Group By PriceDate
```

This will get you something like:

```
12/1/2013    2
12/2/2013    1
....
```

Comment: Don't think I was clear enough.  I have multiple transactions that occur using the same PriceDate so I don't want them to be counted multiple times.  I also have multiple TxnCodes that have the same Price Date but want them to be counted inside their own Group.

Comment: The overall goal is to find out how many times a price was changed during a set period of time. As well as what prices the clients were charged etc....

Comment: Can you update your question with some examples of the data you have in the table for TxnCode and PriceDate and your expected output?

Comment: Done- Multiple TxnCodes and PriceDates.  So I should read the following.  For TxnCode 1514000- should be 1, TxnCode 1516000 should be 2, TxnCode 22120 should be 1.  Hope that clarifies it a little.